# Postgresql subqueries using a calculated column

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I am new to this platform and need to get a value using a column I already calculated. I know I need a subquery, but am confused by the proper syntax.

```
SELECT well_id, reported_date, oil,
  (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(reported_date,
                          LAG(reported_date) OVER w))/3600)::int as hourly_rate,
                         (oil/hourly_rate)::double precision as six
                          FROM public.production
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY well_id ORDER BY well_id, reported_date 
             ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

The error I am getting is
ERROR:  column "hourly_rate" does not exist
LINE 4:        (oil/hourly_rate)::double precision as six
^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "production.hour_rate".
SQL state: 42703
Character: 171
Which I understand...I have tried brackets, naming the sub queries and different tactics.  I know this is a syntax thing can someone please give me a hand.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused with your notation, but it looks like there are parenthesis issues: your `from` statement is not linked to the select.

In my opinion, the best way to manage subqueries is to wrinte someting like this :

```sql
WITH query1 AS (
   select col1, col2
      from table1
),
query2 as (
   select col1, col2
      from query1
   (additional clauses)
),
select (what you want)
 from query2
(additional statements)

Then you can manipulate your data progressively until you have the right organisation of your data for the final select, including aggregations
```

Comment: Let me give this a shot.  Thank you for your help.  I will write back after I try it.

Comment: Bingo thank you so very much.  That's really helped out a lot.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use alias in the select list. YOu need to include the original calculation in the column. So your updated query would look alike -

```
SELECT well_id, reported_date, oil,
       (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(reported_date, LAG(reported_date) OVER w))/3600)::int as hourly_rate,
       (Oil/(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(reported_date, LAG(reported_date) OVER w))/3600))::double precision as six
  FROM public.production
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY well_id ORDER BY well_id, reported_date 
             ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Comment: Thank you this solution works as well.  Appreciate your time